# Prevent rows affected entry in file export from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How can I prevent entries like this:

```
(123456 rows affected)
```

in a text file export at the end of the file. Do not seem to find option. Thanks!

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

> [SET NOCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> **Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.**

Or by enabling the `SET NOCOUNT` option via SSMS:

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8c99360-780d-4bd7-a919-e02339078976/show-number-of-rows-affected-in-management-studio</sup>

Comment: thanks - remember that one now - sorry just getting back into sql server again.