# Persist SET NOCOUNT option etc. in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am pretty sure it must be possible to persist the SET NOCOUNT option via SSMS so that I do not have to reset this every time. See also accepted answer here:

[prevent rows affected entry in file export from ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905794/prevent-rows-affected-entry-in-file-export-from-ssms)

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start SSMS, from the menu open Tools -> Options and go to Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advanced. Then make sure SET NOCOUNT option is selected:
[image]
Next time you open a new query window, it will not show you the record counts and it will persists between restarts.
If you want to do this for the currently opened query window only, from the menu go to Query -> Query options and then to Execution -> Advanced.